# How do I order table columns by the most recent date?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have `email_invitations` table with three datetime columns, `sent_at`, `opened_at`, and `rsvped_at`. How do I sort the three columns by their date in ascending order (most recent at top)?

I'm using `default_scope` in rails:

```
default_scope { order('sent_at ASC' }
```

Here's what I have

```
EmailInvitation
id: 1, sent_at: "2016-03-24", opened_at: "2016-03-25", rsvped_at: "2016-03-25"
id: 2, sent_at: "2016-03-24", opened_at: "2016-03-25", rsvped_at: "2016-04-01"
id: 3, sent_at: "2016-03-23", opened_at: "2016-03-24", rsvped_at: nil
id: 4, sent_at: "2016-03-29", opened_at: nil, rsvped_at: nil
```

Using `EmailInvitation.order(sent_at: :asc, opened_at: :asc, rspved_at: :asc)` it looks like it sorts sent_at first, then opened_at, then rsvped_at.

```
id: 4, sent_at: "2016-03-29", opened_at: nil, rsvped_at: nil
id: 1, sent_at: "2016-03-24", opened_at: "2016-03-25", rsvped_at: "2016-03-25"
id: 2, sent_at: "2016-03-24", opened_at: "2016-03-25", rsvped_at: "2016-04-01"
id: 3, sent_at: "2016-03-23", opened_at: "2016-03-24", rsvped_at: nil
```

but what  I really want whatever has the most recent date will be at the top so somehow I need to join all the columns so it doesn't look at the column name, just the date.

```
id: 2, sent_at: "2016-03-24", opened_at: "2016-03-25", rsvped_at: "2016-04-01"
id: 4, sent_at: "2016-03-29", opened_at: nil, rsvped_at: nil
id: 1, sent_at: "2016-03-24", opened_at: "2016-03-25", rsvped_at: "2016-03-25"
id: 3, sent_at: "2016-03-23", opened_at: "2016-03-24", rsvped_at: nil
```

Comment: Since you are not satisfied with Athonys answer: can you show some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: edit: need ascending order, not descending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably:

1. `sent_at` will never be `nil`.
2. If `opened_at` is `nil` then so is `rsvped_at`.
3. `sent_at` will always be at most `opened_at` or `opened_at` will be `nil`.
4. If `opened_at` is not `nil` then it will always be at most `rsvped_at` or `rsvped_at` will be `nil`.

That means that you're really trying to sort by the first non-`nil` entry in

```
[rsvped_at, opened_at, sent_at]
```

Right? That's that same as trying to pick the first non-NULL entry in that list and sorting by that. That's pretty simple to express using COALESCE:

```
order('coalesce(rsvped_at, opened_at, sent_at) desc')
```

The SQL COALESCE function simply returns the first (from left to right) of its arguments that is not NULL.